# Python recursive XML parsing

Tags: python, xml, parsing

Brand new to XML parsing.  What would be the best way in python to parse something like:

```
<Item name="item1">
    <data>item1data</data>
    <subItems>
        <Item name="item2">
            <data>item2data</data>
            <subItems>
                <Item name="item3">
                  . . .
                </Item>
            </subItems>
        </Item>
        <Item name="item4">
          . . .
        </Item>
    <subItems>
</Item>
```

I was looking at `xml.sax` parsing, but couldn't figure out how to enable it to do multiple levels of parsing down the `subItems` trees.  Could someone give me a recommendation of a parser/method to parse this?  Thank you!

I will be creating lists of 'Item' objects with this, expected results would loopks something like this:

```
[Item(item1, item1data, 
    [Item(item2, item2data, 
        [Item(item3 ... ]) Item(item4 ... )])]`
```

Comment: What are you going to do with it when it's parsed? The `lxml` package is IMO the best to use.

Comment: @Daenyth I will be creating nested lists for display on a GUI

Comment: Edit your question and add some example data structures or output you'd expect to receive after parsing your snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the best ways in python to parse xml is to use the lxml package that can be located at:
http://lxml.de/

It includes backwards compatibility with the python built-in module ElementTree and provides xPath support.

Here's a tutorial to get you started:
http://lxml.de/tutorial.html